# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while reading avro file using BinaryDecoder in java

Tags: binary, avro

I am using avro-1.10.1 jar and below is the sample code.
This is to read avro file data stored on local system. Exception thrown in reader.read method where it's trying to access in.readIndex and fails.

```
DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\QA_1040\\AVRO_UNI.avro"));
BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(inputStream, null);
GenericRecord data = reader.read(null, decoder);



 Error:
    {"type":"record","name":"Root","fields":[{"name":"COL_STR","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"COL_INT","type":["null","long"]}]}
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -40
        at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:460)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:283)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:187)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:259)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
        at gcloud.AvroReadFromLocalFileBinaryDecoder.main(AvroReadFromLocalFileBinaryDecoder.java:55)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the Avro file is binary encoded so you need to decode it first then you need to read the file.

To decode the file in Linux environment we have commands like

```
base64 --decode fileName > newDecodedFileName
base64 --decode Customer.avro > customer_decode.avro
```